# Dataproc exit code 247

Tags: python, pyspark, dataproc

running sparkNLP on DataProc and the code ends abruptly and the only log statement is

```
"Job 'd74196c5-c5e9-4629-a317-20a0f151abf7' completed with exit code 247"
```

What does exit code 247 mean?

Comment: Can you check the logs for that jobID?